# Multiple inheritance issue, add threading.Thread to the class

Tags: python, multithreading, twitter, multiple-inheritance, tweepy

First of all let me explain **what I want to do**:

**Basic overview**:
Get data from twitter in one class and print it in another class.
**Little Deeper:** I want `CustomStreamListener` to be able to run as a separate thread. And Every single status, that I'm getting in `on_status` method put in a queue. Than `Twitter()` class will pull the queue out and print it.

Now **what I don't understand**:

- What I should put in `run()` function? (Should it just call `on_status()`?)
- In case If everything is good with `CustomStreamListener` how should I call it?? ( In order for me to call this class without `Thread` I should do something like this:

  ```
      l = CustomStreamListener()
      stream = tweepy.streaming.Stream(self.auth,l)
      stream.filter(follow=None, track=hashtag)
  ```
- Now If I want to call `threading.Thread` I have to call it with `start()` and than somewhere after pull the queue out. So this part is little confusing for me.

I'm also open to any other way to get similar result. Thank you.

```
    import sys, os, time
    import tweepy
    import simplejson as json
    import threading, Queue

    queue = Queue.Queue()

    #SETTINGS :

    #output = open(os.path.join(os.path.expanduser('~/'), 'sample_file.txt'), 'a')
    hashtag = ['java']

    class CustomStreamListener(tweepy.StreamListener, threading.Thread):

        def __init__(self):
            threading.Thread.__init__(self)
            self.queue = queue

        def on_status(self, status):
            try:
                # If you want to have different data from twitter just change .text to something different from tweet:
                '''
                status.text
                status.author.screen_name
                status.created_at
                status.source
                status.user.screen_name
                status.id
                status.source_url
                status.place
                '''
                time.sleep(0.15)
                data = status.text
                self.queue.put(data)

                #print json.loads(data)
                #with open(os.path.join(os.path.expanduser('~/'), 'sample_file.txt'), 'a') as output:
                #    output.write("%s\n "% data)

            except Exception, e:
                print >> sys.stderr, 'Encountered Exception:', e
                pass

        '''
        def on_data(self, data):
            d = (json.dumps(json.loads(data), indent=4, sort_keys=True))
            print d
            output.write("%s "% d)
        '''

        def on_error(self, status_code):
            print >> sys.stderr, 'Encountered error with status code:', status_code
            return True # Don't kill the stream

        def on_timeout(self):
            print >> sys.stderr, 'Timeout...'
            return True # Don't kill the stream

    class Twitter():

        def __init__(self):

            consumer_key=''
            consumer_secret=''
            access_key = ''
            access_secret = ''

            self.auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
            self.auth.set_access_token(access_key, access_secret)
            self.api = tweepy.API(self.auth)


        def start(self):
            l = CustomStreamListener()
            stream = tweepy.streaming.Stream(self.auth,l)
            stream.filter(follow=None, track=hashtag)

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        Twitter().start()
```

Comment: Is the `filter` function an event loop? Does it basically run forever?

Comment: Yes, filter function is part of the stream, and it will run forever.

Answer (score 0):

```
stream.filter(follow=None, track=hashtag)
```

You want to make this function call from the `run` method, in order to run the event loop in the other thread.

Perhaps easier would be to construct a `threading.Thread` directly in `Twitter.start`. Then the listener object does not need to know the parameters you want to pass to `filter`. In this appoach, `CustomStreamListener` would not subclass `threading.Thread`.

```
class Twitter():
    def start(self):
        l = CustomStreamListener()
        stream = tweepy.streaming.Stream(self.auth,l)
        self.listener_thread = threading.Thread(target=stream.filter, 
                                                kwargs=dict(follow=None, track=hashtag))
        self.listener_thread.start()
```

Comment: I was thinking about this also, but, what would I put in q query?

Comment: @Vor By query, do you mean the parameters `follow` and `track`? See edited answer.